# Complete Symfony2 Tutorial

Tags: php, symfony

Do any body know any Complete Symfony2 Tutorial?

I've been looking for a complete Symfony2 tutorial to make a Dynamic Webpage the same as Jobeet did for Symfony.

I tried Symblog but it is not a full complete tutorial.

I also would like to understand why there is a lack of this material available also I didn't find books with complete examples like for Symfony1.

Cheers ;)

Comment: For symblog did you download the complete source code that goes along with the tutorial? https://github.com/dsyph3r/symblog

Comment: I saw it on GitHub and downloaded it but it would be nice to have a complete step by step process. I'm too noob to understand raw code :(

Comment: The link symblog is for Symfony 2.0.  Stay away from it.  This chapter is a good place for beginners to start: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/from_flat_php_to_symfony2.html

Comment: Hi I found several resources that I think are very useful:

Quick Intro:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/diving-into-symfony-2-2/

Symfony2 Cheesheat:
http://www.symfony2cheatsheet.com

Other option for a Jobeet tutorial for S2. 
http://www.intelligentbee.com/blog/2013/08/07/symfony2-jobeet-day-1-starting-up-the-project/

If you know spanish this is it: http://symfony.es/noticias/2011/10/03/cupon-una-nueva-aplicacion-de-ejemplo-de-symfony2/

Answer (score 8):

Check this out: this is the full book, follow it and you will have a good website in just a few time

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/index.html

Comment: And this is the best start point.

Comment: I've been reading the book and it's very complete. In my case I'm a complete beginner with Web Development, I just finished my first webpage with php, mysql and JS and it would be very clarifying to see a complete protect step by step :). Now I want to learn a good FM to create good dynamic webpages, from something 9GAG style to udemy. Is Symfony2 OverKill option?

Comment: Symfony2 in my opinion, is a good framework for little and medium websites, because you don't have to waste alot of time for easy functions - the framework just gives you everything you need. for example: You got a terminal in which you can type console commands. if you do that - the framework itself, generates you all kinds of data, you need for dynamic websites, without even writing any code! In my opinion its a very good framework and I can just recommend it!

Comment: You should start, by just setting up a Symfony project on your local system, and downloading a bundle. for example the FOSUserBundle. Read the documentation of this bundle, and you will see how the MVC(Model view Controller) works in Symfony2. In general: You are just adding bundles(part of a website). And when you got alot of bundles, they all work together and give you the finished website. Documentation of Bundles will tell you alot!

Comment: Addition to my comment before: Symfony2 can be a great framework for big websites with a lot of traffic aswell as long as you don't loose the overview :)